# Why ‘over and over’ can add ‘again’?

Tags: grammar, word-usage

> The police questioned the men *over and over **again***.

‘over and over’ is meaning ‘repeatedly’, and ‘again’ is meaning ‘repeatedly’ too. So ‘over and over again’ is a little weird, I feel.

Answer (score 1):

"Again" does not mean repeatedly - it means that something has been repeated *once*.

Example:

> I am going to London again.

This doesn't mean that you are repeatedly going to London - just that you are going, and you have been before, at least once.

"Over and over again" idiomatically means repeatedly. We also sometimes say "*again and again*" to mean repeatedly.

Your sentence intends to show that the man was questioned repeatedly, and the word "again" alone would not show that.

> The police questioned the men again.

This would simply mean that they questioned them a second time.

Comment: But should ‘repeatedly’ cover ‘repeated once’?

Comment: No. "Repeated" means something is done again, once. "Repeated**ly**" is an adverb that denotes something ongoing. In fact the Oxford dictionary definition of "repeatedly" is "*over and over again; constantly*" if you needed proof that "over and over again" is an English idiom.

Comment: I know now. It is very clear

Comment: Redundancy is often used where emphasis or vividness of description is desired. I spun round and round and round, over and over and over again, until I was nearly sick.

Comment: over and over with or without again **means** repeatedly.

Answer (score 0):

In "over and over again", "again" is related to the second "over".

Without being totally (grammatically) correct, the expression can be understood as:

> 1. He did X.
> 2. He did X and (even) over.
> 3. He did X and over and again over.
> 4. He did X and **over and again over**.

In the second "step", over can mean "more", or "again".

In the third "step", you can already spot the "over and over again" (highlighted in "step" 4), with the order of words changed.

Comment: 2. is not really right....

Answer (score 0):

> The police questioned me *over and over*

This usually means they constantly asked the same set of questions during an interview/interrogation session

Adding *again* means that they did the same thing on a subsequent occasion (could be 2nd/3rd/4th/etc)